# How to convert byte to hexadecimal string in Java

Tags: java, hex, type-conversion, byte, arrays

I have a MAC address represented as a byte[] in Java and want it as a hexadecimal string, as they are usually represented. How can I do this with as easy as possible?

The byte array has length 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
String hexValue = String.format("%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X:%02X", mac[0], mac[1], mac[2], mac[3], mac[4], mac[5]);
```

Comment: This works and the formating is perfect.